# php parse javascript generated text

Tags: php, javascript, parsing

let's say that on some site there are some div elements, which content is generated by javascript. I want to code a PHP script, that will get that content and store it to some variable. I know how to parse text using PHP, I just don't know how to get to the javascript generated output (not JavaScript code!) and store it to PHP variable. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have access to the javascript? if so it seems you should be pushing from javascript to php and not trying to parse the generated html.  You would need to interpret the javascript to get that to work which is done by the browser...

Comment: If the text is generated by JavaScript PHP has no direct access to it, except by using Ajax to submit that text to a server side script.

Comment: At the time you get the page, is the generated content already in or is it generated by the browser only if you watch the page?

Comment: no, i don't have access to the javascript. every time i reload the page, new content is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could post the HTML back to your PHP script. Assuming that the javascript code fills out an element with `id="foo"`...

```
var generatedHTML = document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;
```

Then you could use whatever AJAX library you might have (eg: jQuery) to post it to a server for processing.

(Or you could process it on the client side..!)